# Firebase Phone Authentication Error: The SMS Code Has Expired

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Having implemented the FireBase phone authentication as per the documentation, I get several problems.

1. some numbers cannot be authenticated: I am using Airtel as my service provider.

On the log, I can confirm that the code has been sent but I haven't received it on my phone:

> D/PhoneAuthenticating: onCodeSent:AM5PThBss5tbYdpNW5R9Q7o8zOYeHvd7lnZ1KBlS...

2. Switching to another carrier, I can receive the code but then it says the SMS code has expired immediately after trying to verify. I make more attempts and result is the same

> W/PhoneAuthenticating: signInWithCredential:failure
>                                                                                     com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.nf.zzK(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.mg.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.oa.zzL(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.oc.onFailure(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.nj.onTransact(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)

This exception is thrown:

> FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException

code expiry takes more in than 3599 seconds in firebase. The time taken to verify is less than a minute

Comment: I keep getting the same error as you but on iOS. I dont know what im doing wrong

Comment: Did you find any solution? @Lucem

Comment: Yes @AtulRaj please check my code below

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Finally got the solution.
During authenticating the user, we use the same method for sending the code only that we add a new parameter.

```
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential)
    Toast.makeText(this, "Verifying...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: it's suppose to be FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithCredential(credential) instead of signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);

Comment: @RedM I bet that signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(..) is his own method, which will call exactly that ;)

Answer (score 7):

Just so that you know there's an auto retrieval section in firebase phone authentication which will read sms and invalidate it in the background. The callback for that auto-retrieval should be used to authenticate your user without him entering the sms manually.

Answer (score 1):

While setting the PhoneVerificationCompleted handler, you need to the following,

1. Comment the line,

   //_firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
2. Replace AuthCredential with PhoneAuthCredential,

   PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
   (***PhoneAuthCredential*** phoneAuthCredential)
3. Add async to this method,

   PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
   (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) ***async***

It should work fine!