# Sms is not Verified in Firebase

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-authentication

I am working in Firebase SMS. I have downloaded the Firebase quick start unity 2018.3.7f1. I have followed all the methods adding (googleservices.json, sha1  method) While running the app the  sms is received in my phone.

But the problem is when i entered  the sms and try to authenticate the sms.The firebase displayed the error .

Sign in encounter an error.

> AuthError:Session Expired
>
> Firebase.FirebaseException: The sms code has expired.Please re-send 
>   the verification code to try again.

actually entered within the seconds. But it  says the above error.

Any one can give the suggestion. How to solve this error.

[image: sms]

Comment: maybe this answer could help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522726/firebase-phone-authentication-error-the-sms-code-has-expired

Comment: @Frank thanks for your help. Actually Firebase is automatically detecting the sms..